# How to Quickly Assign Letter Counts from Lists to Variables in Python

Tags: python, variables, python-3.x, count

Basically I have a list of (for all intents and purposes) random letters. The letters are not really random, they do have significance; however, it really isn't important for the question. The lists would look something like this:

```
list = ['v', 'f', 't', 'w', 'w', 'i', 'b']
```

the real lists are significantly longer (up to 100 characters). I want to count how many times each letter appears and assign that to a variable that is that letter. For example:

```
a = list.count('a')
b = list.count('b')
c = list.count('c')
...
...
z = list.count('z')
```

I just want to know if there is a simpler way to do this instead of typing the same line 26 times. I am running Python 3.4. I want to be able to do it in as few lines and as few characters as possible. Any suggestions would be helpful, thank you.

Comment: You really shouldn't use separate variables for these counts. What happens when you need to get the count of some letter determined at runtime? `if letter == 'a': return a elif letter == 'b': return b elif letter == 'c': return c...`. It's much better to use something like a dict.

Answer (score 2):

```
import collections

counts = collections.Counter(l)
```

`counts['a']` is then the number of occurrences of `a`. With a list of length `L` and `N` possible different items, this runs in `O(L)` time instead of the `O(NL)` a `list.count`-based solution would take, and it's less code.

Comment: This is the `one obvious way to do it`.

Answer (score 0):

### Simple approach #1

```
import string
x = string.ascii_lowercase #  'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
l = ['v', 'f', 't', 'w', 'w', 'i', 'b']
d = {}
for i in x:
  d[i] = l.count(i)
```

### Slightly fancier approach #2

```
import string
x = string.ascii_lowercase #  'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
l = ['v', 'f', 't', 'w', 'w', 'i', 'b']
d = dict([(i, l.count(i)) for i in x])
```

Now `d` will contain something similar to:

```
{
  'a': 2,
  'b': 3,
  'c': 0,
  ...
}
```

Comment: This works, but it's a bad idea to get into the habit of computing counts like this. When the number of distinct possible list items grows, this kind of solution takes a really long time to finish.

Comment: His question specifically asked for the count of each character in the range of `a-z`, so this solution fits the bill quite nicely.

Comment: It works now, but it's a bad idea to get into the habit of using solutions with poor asymptotic complexity just because the parameters aren't very large, especially when the solutions with better complexity are just as simple or simpler to write.

Answer (score 0):

This method uses a dictionary to assign the count for each letter rather than use the actual letter itself.

```
from collections import Counter
import string

dictionary = dict(Counter(l))

>>> dictionary
{'b': 1, 'f': 1, 'i': 1, 't': 1, 'v': 1, 'w': 2}

>>> dictionary['w']
2
```

If you require a full dictionary of each letter, you can extend it as follows:

```
letters = string.ascii_lowercase
dictionary.update({c: 0 for c in letters if c not in dictionary})

>>>> dictionary
{'a': 0,
 'b': 1,
 'c': 0,
 'd': 0,
 'e': 0,
 'f': 1,
 'g': 0,
 'h': 0,
 'i': 1,
 'j': 0,
 'k': 0,
 'l': 0,
 'm': 0,
 'n': 0,
 'o': 0,
 'p': 0,
 'q': 0,
 'r': 0,
 's': 0,
 't': 1,
 'u': 0,
 'v': 1,
 'w': 2,
 'x': 0,
 'y': 0,
 'z': 0}
```

Or you could simply use letter_count = dictionary.get(letter, 0) on the original dictionary to return zero for any letter not in the dictionary.

Comment: That could be written simpler as `d = dict(Counter(l))`, if you need a dict rather than a Counter for some reason.

Comment: @user2357112 depends... if a letter isn't present a `Counter` will return `0` which I imagine is probably correct, rather than `KeyError`'ing

Comment: Yeah... looking at the OPs requirements a bit more `dictionary['a']` should return `0` instead of forcing a `dict.get` or a `KeyError`...

Comment: Ambiguous... ("I want to count how many times each letter appears and assign that to a variable that is that letter").  Anyway, I updated a method to extend the dictionary.

Comment: @Alexander not really... if they're typing the same line out 26 times, then each name will be assigned a value, even if it's `0` (eg - no missing names/keys)

Comment: Could do it the other way around... `dictionary = dict.fromkeys(letters, 0); dictionary.update(Counter(l))` - avoids the dict-comp and `if` condition... (and you'll still get the same behaviour)

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do it with no import necessary. Since you said you are expecting up to 100 chars, which is still a small set, I wouldn't worry to much on computational complexity cost.

```
list(set(zip(l,[l.count(x) for x in l])))
```